# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource in angular 9 and spring boot 2

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I added spring security to the spring boot application and I have some api end points that  needs to be called no matter user login or not.(I mean these are the rest end points where I need to retrieve data in my front side angular).

So,I config it as:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
 
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;
 
 
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
 
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
         .userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService)
         .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
 
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    
           http.csrf().
           disable()
               .authorizeRequests()
               .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")
               .permitAll()
              .antMatchers("/books").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/v1/search/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
               .anyRequest()
               .authenticated()
               .and()
               .httpBasic();
              
    }
 
}
```

I have all the api exposed from : `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/` like:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/v1/books
http://localhost:8080/api/v1/bookcategory
```

I have configured using `.antMatchers("/api/v1/search/**")`,and my config for restendpoint is:

```
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins ="http://localhost:4200")
public class BasicAuthController {

    @GetMapping(path = "/basicauth")
    public AuthenticationBean basicauth() {
        System.out.println("hitted here");
        return new AuthenticationBean("You are authenticated");
    }
    
  
}
```

I allowed the csfr policy using:

```
@Configuration
public class RepositoryConfig implements RepositoryRestConfigurer{

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;
    
    @Override
    public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
        config.exposeIdsFor(entityManager.getMetamodel().getEntities().stream()
                .map(Type::getJavaType).toArray(Class[]::new));
        
        
        //to handle cross origin
        config.getCorsRegistry().addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
    }
}
```

BookRepository.java

```
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book,Long> {

    @RestResource(path = "categoryid")
    Page<Book>  findByCategoryId(@Param("id") Long id,Pageable pageable);
    
    //to get book by searching
    @RestResource(path = "searchbykeyword")
    Page<Book>  findByNameContaining(@Param("xyz") String keyword,Pageable pageable);
}
```

front side I have angular 9 as:

auth.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

   // BASE_PATH: 'http://localhost:8080'
   USER_NAME_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME = 'authenticatedUser';

   public username: String;
   public password: String;
 
   constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
 
   }
 
   authenticationService(username: String, password: String) {
     return this.http.get(`http://localhost:8080/api/v1/basicauth`,
       { headers: { authorization: this.createBasicAuthToken(username, password) } }).pipe(map((res) => {
         this.username = username;
         this.password = password;
         this.registerSuccessfulLogin(username, password);
       }));
   }
 
   createBasicAuthToken(username: String, password: String) {
     return 'Basic ' + window.btoa(username + ":" + password)
   }

}
```

//i didnot pasted all the codes.

So,I get error as when I goto link http://localhost:4200/books:

[image]

Comment: can you please try the `localhost:8080/api/...` with `OPTIONS` method from postman and see if there is a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header returned and it has value of either `localhost:4200` or `*`, read more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS

Comment: I tried this in postman : curl -X OPTIONS http://localhost:8080/api/v1/books  -i and i got could not get any response

Comment: are you sure that this endpoint you are calling from angular is correct? I've been working with angular+springboot and I've realized that when angular doesn't find the destination, the browser sends a CORS error

Comment: yes,the login happens succesfuly when i send username and pasword from angular and when i just hit the rest endpoints on my browser i see the data,but the same destination link is said as CSRF policy when those api are getting fetched from angular

Comment: if don't get a response when using OPTIONS, this means you are not configuring your API to catch this method, you have to add it

Comment: you can also setup a local proxy to do this instead of building it into your API

Comment: can u please show me the example?

Comment: add ` http.csrf()..cors().` in configurer it should work.

Comment: can u show me exmaple @sil

Comment: Define WebMvcConfigurer bean and override addCorsMappings method and enable CORS. Can you try adding it as shown here - https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/

Comment: Canu shkw me example @govind

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/cors.html or https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-cors-preflight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have some projects using Angular+SpringBoot with security and I create a specific Bean to handle with CORS and I never have problem. If you can try, add this method bellow in your WebSecurityConfig class:

```
@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:4200", "http://localhost:8080"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "PUT", "POST","OPTIONS", "DELETE"));
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("authorization","content-type"));
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}
```

Comment: which packge should i import ,cors or .cors.reactive?

Comment: import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;

Comment: using this bean you dont need to use the @CrossOrigin annotation in the controllers

Comment: still the same error Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/book-category' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: I think that you are not calling the correct endpoint address. try to remove the Spring Security lib and call again this endpoint. maybe you will receive the same error. as I told before, I've realized that sometimes when the browser doesn't find the correct destination, it shows the CORS error

Comment: it was working fine but when i added spring secutiry then i got such error message.

Comment: ok, now my sugestion is kind of try and error, but try to add .cors in the configure method of WebSecurityConfig class: something like this: http.csrf().disable()
   .cors().and()
   .authorizeRequests(). .................

Comment: i added the   http.csrf().disable() .cors().and() .authorizeRequests(). but now my spring secutiry is not working it doensot ask username and password

Answer (score 1):

The problem is CORS which is a security feature of your browser. It ensures that only resources form the same domain (and port!) can be accessed. Your Angular development server and the Tomcat run on a different port which causes the request to be declined. You have to configure CORS. However, you should know what you are doing because you are basically disabling a security feature. Usually it is not a problem tho. You can do this by adding the annotation @CrossOrigin to your controller methods or by using the Java configuration. For the second cause, I'm sure you'll easily find it on Google :)

Comment: i have added @crossorigin to the every rest end points but it is still not working

Answer (score 0):

CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) is a security feature of your browser that prevent authorized sites from using Resources from another origin

in nutshell it happens if your site on x:y origin and requesting resources from a:y, x:b or a:b origins (different port and/or domain)

what exactly happens in nutshell when this is the case

if you made a get (or post...) request from another origin, the browser will first make an `option` request to the same endpoint, if it's succeeded and has all the allowing headers it will make the get request, if not it will throw the error specifying why it was denied and don't make the original request

so we have two cases now, it's either the headers is returned only on the get request, but not the options one, or it's never returned